# Make plot line visible under plot area

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I have type: 'area' plot, the area job is to make plot lines under it 50% opacity.
The issue is that the plot lines aren't visible until I hover over the area as you can see on the screens:
[image: not hovered]

[image: hovered]

I'm using mui alpha to set transparency on the plot area.

```
        color: alpha(palette.background.paper, 0.5),
```

Is there any way to make it work as I want to?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure If I fully understand your issue. Could you please reproduce your example in the simplified demo? You can start here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zb9tnxLa/

Comment: Hi, sure, its a simple example https://jsfiddle.net/qy74skgv/29/

Comment: It seems to have some unexpected behaviour because now, it's displaying correctly in my env.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to provided demo, the 'graph' series isn't visible due to 'lineWidth' set to 0. The line appears during hover because the default `lineWidthPlus` property dictates how much to increase the linewidth from the normal state.

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.states.hover

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aznbyqL5/